# How do you alter /.meteor/local/build/static_cacheable/packages without them being overridden?

Tags: javascript, meteor, meteorite

jquery is being loaded there and as a result, I can't change my version of jquery being used.  I want to upgrade it to jquery 2.03.  When I tried adding jquery 2.03 to my public directory my browser was still recognizing the jquery located in my packages folder.  How do I override those files?

Comment: Voting to reopen. Although the question is not the best, I can still understand it as a Meteor user. I'm guess the people who closed it haven't used meteor before.

Comment: Thanks @andrewMao this is a very perplexing issue.

Answer (score 1):

You can create your own local jQuery package by copying jquery folder from `~/.meteor/packages/jquery` to your project's `packages` folder. Then make all fixes you need in your local copy. Don't forget to `meteor remove jquery` to remove standard package.

Or just include jquery.min.js from cdn in your html's head.

Comment: I'll give this a shot.  The thing is, jquery isn't even installed as a package when I view the lists.  I'm guessing it was installed as a bootstrap dependency, but I really don't know.

Comment: Correct, jquery package is a dependency of bootstrap. You can look at package.js file of any package (in .meteor/packages for example), that's where all dependencies are listed. I wonder, will your local package called `jquery` override the built-in package and act as dependency of bootstrap

Comment: Unfortunately, it isn't acting as an override to that dependency.

Comment: That's sad, the easiest 'hack' I could recommend is copying both 'bootstrap' and 'jquery' packages to your local packages folder and modifying them in the way you want. Don't forget to remove built-in packages with `meteor remove bootstrap`.